# fixed position with newfloat

Tags: floats, minted, newfloat

Listed code renders text with *some text related to the third listing* above source code with *cat file2*. Forced positioning with **H** solves the problem however this option is not available in `newfloat` package which I'd like to use because of more captioning control (TBH the goal is to reduce spacing between `minted` and `caption`).

Is there a way to set fixed position with `newfloat`?

I'm new to LATeX so maybe different approach should be used?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  portrait,
  margin=2cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{minted} % color source code files

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
some text related to the first listing
\begin{listing}[!ht]
  \caption[firstlisting]{firstlisting}
  \begin{minted}[frame=single]{console}
    cat file1
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
    first listing
  \end{minted}
\end{listing}

some text related to the second listing
\begin{listing}[!ht]
  \caption[secondlisting]{secondlisting}
  \begin{minted}[frame=single]{console}
    cat file2
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
    second listing
  \end{minted}
\end{listing}

some text related to the third listing
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE :) // I assume we don't need all those listing-lines ... Can you please delete as many of them while still preserving your problem? // Which Editor or approach do you use to compile Latex?

Comment: True, sorry about that. // There must be enough lines so secondlisting moves to the second page. // I use VScode with pdflatex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `H` float placement option, load the `float` package additionally. To my knowledge there is no incompatibility with the `newfloat` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,newfloat,lipsum}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{demo}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{demo}[H]
\centering
Whatever\ldots
\caption{A useless demo}
\end{demo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```